# TeamSpeak mutes other applications

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, telephony, teamspeak

As soon as I start TeamSpeak other applications (e.g. FireFox, VLC Player, ...) gets muted. Additionally, these applications get muted again (after I un-muted them manually) from time to time while TeamSpeak is running.

I know that I had the same problem with older versions of Mumble. I remember some Mumble-dev stating that Mumble once was registered as "phone application", thus the PulseAudio or so mutes other applications while "phone applications" are running.

Newer versions of Mumble do not have this issue, because they are running as "Games" or something like that.

However, like always, the TeamSpeak devs are not helping at all. Hence, I thought maybe I can force PulseAudio to stop this stupid auto-muting.

Does somebody know if PulseAudio can be configured to stop auto-muting applications when "phone applications" are running? Or generally turning off any auto-mute functionality? I want to *always* control volume/mute myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the superuser community [this](https://superuser.com/questions/431079/how-to-disable-auto-mute-mode) solution was recommended by the user Sam Watkins.

> You can make this automatic on boot by executing (perhaps in /etc/rc.local): `/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 sset "Auto-Mute Mode" Disabled`

Comment: Normally, this should solve the problem. In my case it did not :/ If I start `alsamixer` I have two soundcards `PulseAudio` and `Realtek ALC293`. Auto-Mute is disabled for the Realtek Card, but PulseAudio does not offer an Auto-Mute option and `alsamixer` says that `PulseAudio` is default -.-"

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought that what fixed it for me was setting TeamSpeak to use ALSA in capture and playback options.

However, I actually found the real cause behind this happening. It's pusleaudio plugin called Cork. Apparently it's buggy and it doesn't play well with Qt applications. If you don't want other sources muted when using voice streams in Qt applications you'll have to either comment out or remove the line in the `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

`load-module module-cork-music-on-phone`